# Code is not printing anything

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to take input from the console, but nothing is getting printed. I debugged the code and it's correctly storing values in the array, but nothing is getting printed. I am new to java. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class noofdays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] date = new int[10];
        int i = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            date[i]=in.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(date[i]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `while` loop doing here?

Comment: Use a Debugger and you will foind out what is happend

Comment: while loop is for getting input from console @AsteriskNinja

Comment: you sure ? only two things can cause trouble , invalid input or lengthy input

Comment: I have used debugger but the debugger is not proceeding after while loop @Jens

Comment: how would you break out of the `while` loop?

Comment: @PavneetSingh I am sure

Comment: when the in.hasNext() will reutun a false value then

Comment: @user3797489 Then set the breakpoint before the Loop and you will see the problem

Comment: Looks like you have infinite loop here

Comment: dude i told you the problematic cases and plus you have to give invalid input (string)  to print something, beauty of flaw in your logic

Comment: @Simze what can be done to break the loop

Comment: try this input `1
2
3
invalid`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code! It starts without any output and the user can input numbers (hit enter to confirm). Once the user inputs something else, the `while-loop` terminates and the `for-loop` starts printing the numbers. You may want some more error handling (what happens when the user inputs a `float` ?) and maybe some output to guide the user. But besides that, everything works as it should.

Comment: What's stopping your while loop?  (Hint: Nothing except running off the end of your input array)

Comment: Use a typed list rather than a fixed size array. This will solve one issue, where more than 10 integers are contained in the arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get out of while loop in java with Scanner method "hasNext" as condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490344/how-to-get-out-of-while-loop-in-java-with-scanner-method-hasnext-as-condition)

Comment: Everything works fine for me http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/bAiL9M maybe there is some problem in the way you providing the input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find anything *wrong* with your code, it may just behave a little different than you expect. So here is how I would do it.

One thing first: class names should always start with a capital letter (not an error but rather a convention that helps to understand the code)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    int[] date = new int[10];      // as mentioned above, a fixed size array will limit you - but if 10 is what you want, then this is what you need
    int i = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter " + date.length + " numbers");  // just some output to tell the user that the program has started and what to do next
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);      // perfect
    // if you absolutely want your array filled, check if you reached the end of your input to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.
    // in.hasNext() will check for ANY input, which makes it easier to handle unwanted user input
    while(i < date.length && in.hasNext()){   
        if(in.hasNextInt()){        // here you check if the input starts with a number. Beware that "1 w 2" is valid too!
            date[i] = in.nextInt();
            i++;   
        }else{
            // this is to advise the user of an input error
            // but more importantly, in.next() will read the invalid input and remove it from the inputstream. Thus your scanner will continue to read the input until it ends
            System.out.println("sorry \"" + in.next() + "\" is not a valid number"); 
        }
    }
    System.out.println("your input:");  
    for(i = 0; i < date.length; i++){    // you don't need any advanced loops, it is perfectly fine to use indexed loops. Just try to make your break condition more dynamic (like checking the length of the array instead of a constant value)
        System.out.println(date[i]);
    }
}
```

This is neither a solution, nor the best way to do it. I am merely trying to show you how you can guide your user and handle unwanted input.

**edit**: in a nutshell, these things should be considered:

- don't make any assumption on the intelligence of your user, he/she could input anything: `1 two 2.3 , 4 . @¹"`
- be sure you want `10` numbers, otherwise either use an array of a different size, or a list (if you don't know how many numbers you need)
- maybe the user doesn't want to input as many numbers and wants to quit earlier ( `if(in.next().equalsIgnoreCase("q")` could do the trick )
- do you accept any integers? even negative ones?
- should you accept `long` as well or even `BigInteger` ?
- what about floating points?
- and how do you want to handle the error? ignore it, replace it with a default value, exit the loop or even the program?

And here are some example runs:

```
Please enter 10 numbers
1 
2
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10
your input:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Please enter 10 numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
your input:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Please enter 10 numbers
1 2 3 4 r 5 6 7 8 9 10
sorry "r" is not a valid number
your input:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Please enter 10 numbers
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
your input:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

because the loop  will not stop:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            date[i]=in.nextInt();
            i++;
 }
```

so the code cannot  be executed:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(date[i]);
}
```

may  be you can use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] date = new int[10];
            int i = 0;
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
            for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
                date[i]=in.nextInt();
            }

            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(date[i]);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, you've run into an infinite loop in the `while` and this seems like the obvious choice to replace what you're trying to do.

Comment: @px06 there is no infinite loop in the OP question.

Comment: @John it seems that way because the Scanner will keep reading input until it reaches some "end" condition which doesn't seem to happen in the context. [This explains it a little better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490344/how-to-get-out-of-while-loop-in-java-with-scanner-method-hasnext-as-condition).

Comment: @px06 i also didnt find any infinite loop in this question

Comment: @px06 i am aware of what is happening. Scanner is simply blocked until character is read. But this is not infinite loop, which by definition always evaluates to true.

Comment: @John my mis-phrasing then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your loop where to stop waiting for input. If you want to enter a line of `integers` you could just use `nextLine()` and use that `String` instead.

This example will take one line of input and output valid ints.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // use a List, unless you want to enter exactly 10 integers
    List<Integer> date = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    int i = 0;
    String x = "";

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x =  in.nextLine();

    String [] tokens = x.split(" "); 


    for (int y = 0; y < tokens.length; y++) {
        try {
            date.add(Integer.parseInt(tokens[y]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // error handling
            date.add(-1); // set a default value instead or just do nothing
        }
    }

    in.close(); // don't forget to close your Scanner

    for (i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(date.get(i));
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1 2 3.5 foo 50 bar 1234
```

Output:

```
1
2
-1
-1
50
-1
1234
```

Answer (score -2):

int[] date = new int[10];
    int i=0;

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while (in.hasNextInt()) {

        date[i]=in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(date[i]);
        i++;

    }
```

Comment: would you mind explaining how this solves OPs problem?