# How to read Multiple line input

Tags: java

I'm trying to read multiple line input like a copy past input, but I can't end the `while` loop to stop reading. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input =null;
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            input=sc.next();

        }
        String [] split = input.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0;i<split.length;i++) {
            for(int j = split[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--) {
                System.out.print(split[i].charAt(j));
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use buffer reader class, by this you'll be able to take multiple inputs at the same time.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 2):

The `hasNext()` method will look if there is something to read. To do so it might block and wait on the used `InputStream` as described in the [documentation of `hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--):

> `public boolean hasNext()`
>
> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

When the `InputStream` ends it will return from the `hasNext()` call and return `false`, since there is no token to read (and the source of data/bytes is closed). But since you are reading from the keyboard via `System.in` there is no "end" of input because you still can enter new text into your application, which your `while()` loop will read.

There are several solutions for this:

1. Depending on how you start your java application, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to explicit close the so called "STDIN" stream which is "attached" to your keyboard input. That way the stream `System.in` will end and no further data can be read. This is also detected by the `Scanner`s `hasNext()` method, which will return `false` at that point.
2. You can call your java application where you provide the data for the "STDIN" stream via a file or via other commands. Examples of these are: `echo "data" | java Main` or `java Main < inputData.txt` (depending on the terminal/console you are using).
3. Add an end marker to your content and look for it. When you place a text like `"MY_TEXT_END"` in your data and look for it you can use a simple `equals()` check inside the `while()` loop and stop reading when you have seen your marker `"MY_TEXT_END"`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `while` loop and it will loop/execute through a block of code as long as a specified condition is true/met.

And here you are checking any condition to exit the loop.This method may block while waiting for input to scan and the scanner does not advance past any input.

Another gap that I see is, you are re-assigning the input to `input` var again and again without performing any operation beforehand accepting next line.

You can get more clarity on exiting the while loop here :

[How to get out of while loop in java with Scanner method "hasNext" as condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490344/how-to-get-out-of-while-loop-in-java-with-scanner-method-hasnext-as-condition)

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    while(sc.hasNext() && !(input = sc.next()).equals("exit")) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    sc.close();
```

So, to answer your question, you must provide some check/exit condition for while loop to in-validate and exit out of the loop.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help, i have already tried it after all that initial code and at some point i got it but only to a unique text.

Comment: for example to exit the loop i used the number of lines or when it reaches an empty line the problem is that the text given is composed by this : (next comment) it has a blank line in the middle of the text like a double (Enter)