# How to use Scanner hasNextInt() inside a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I cannot get out of while loop.

I do not why `sc.hasNextInt()` does not return false after last read number.

Should I use another method or is there a mistake in my code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creating an array by user keyboard input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Length of array: ");
        int[] numbers = new int[sc.nextInt()];

        System.out.printf("Type in integer elements of array ", numbers.length);
        int index = 0;
        **while ( sc.hasNextInt()) {**
            numbers[index++] = sc.nextInt();


        }
        // created method for printing arrays
        printArray(numbers);
        sc.close();


}
```

Comment: How does it know when the last number is? It's reading from the keyboard, it cannot read your mind to know when to stop asking.

Comment: You should use the input array length as the terminator of the loop.  Check out my answer.

Comment: It should stop asking after hasNextInt() return false. But I cannot understand why it doesnt?

Comment: It will only stop if you type in a non integer (e.g. a letter).

Comment: @WJS thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

When you are receiving your input from the console, the Scanner `hasNextInt()` method placed inside a `while` loop condition will continue to read (meaning the loop will continue), until one of the following happens:

- You submit a non-numeric symbol (e.g. a letter).
- You submit a so-called "[end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10490358/11812518)" character, which is a special symbol telling the Scanner to stop reading.

Thus, in your case you cannot have the `hasNextInt()` inside your while loop condition - I am showing a solution below with a counter variable that you can use.

**However**, the `hasNextInt()` method inside a `while` loop has its practical usage for when reading from a different source than the console - e.g. from a String or a file. Inspired from the examples [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-scanner-hasnextint-method), suppose we have:

```
String s = "Hello World! 3 + 3.0 = 6 ";
```

We can then pass the string `s` as an input source to the Scanner (notice that we are not passing `System.in` to the constructor):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
```

Then loop until `hasNext()`, which checks if there is another token of any type in the input. Inside the loop, perform a check if this token is an int using `hasNextInt()` and print it, otherwise pass the token to the next one using `next()`:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Found int value: " + scanner.next());
    } else {
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Found int value: 3
Found int value: 6
```

In the example above, we cannot use `hasNextInt()` in the while loop condition itself, because the method returns false on the first non-int character that it finds (so the loop closes immediately, as our String begins with a letter).

However, we could use `while (hasNextInt())` to read the [list of numbers from a file](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/Java5/Notes/chap23/ch23_6.html).

**Now, the solution to your problem** would be to place the `index` variable inside the while loop condition:

```
while (index < numbers.length) {
    numbers[index++] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Or for clarity`s sake, make a specific counter variable:

```
int index = 0;
int counter = 0;
while (counter < numbers.length) {
       numbers[index++] = sc.nextInt();
       counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But is possible to write it hasNextInt() method?

Comment: If you write it with hasNextInt() method and you are receiving input from the console, the Scanner will loop until you pass a non-int character (a letter for example) or a special symbol that marks the end of the program. But in your case, this is not what you want. A practical example for using hasNextInt() in the loop condition is when you are not reading input from the console, but from a String - the Scanner will then parse the String until it has a next int and stop at the end - see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @PetarBivolarski great explanation; I would put that in the main respond as to why `hasNextInt()` wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kousha, I updated my answer with an elaborate explanation (in the process I noticed a small mistake in my comment above too, as hasNext() parses a String to the end, not hasNextInt() - it stops / returns false on the first non-int character it finds).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Use the input length as the end of the loop.

```
        // Creating an array by user keyboard input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Length of array: ");

        int len = sc.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[len]; // use len here

        System.out.printf("Type in integer elements of array ", numbers.length);
        int index = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < len; index++) { // and use len here
            numbers[index] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        // created method for printing arrays
        printArray(numbers);
        sc.close();
```

And don't close the scanner.

Comment: Why should scanner be left open?

Comment: In general it's a bad habit to get into.  Try this.  close the Scanner.  Then in the same program, try creating a new one using `System.in`.  The problem is that when you close the scanner it also closes the underlying input stream if one exists.