# Why is my print statement producing no output after a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

What's wrong with this version of this code? (I read something about an "incorrect exit condition" but I don't see how that could be?)

```
import java.util.*;

public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> lineOne = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(scan.hasNext()){
              String lineOneVar = scan.next();
              lineOne.add(lineOneVar);
              /*System.out.println(lineOneVar);
              System.out.println(lineOne);
              System.out.println(lineOne.get(0));*/
        }

        System.out.println(lineOne);
        //Does not produce an output.
    }
}
```

Comment: scan.hasNext(). do you think that returns true? Have you debugged to check? or, just add some print statements in that loop to verify

Comment: @Stultuske it does work, the print statements that I commented do print both arrays and indexes as expected

Comment: that should give you some insight. You never break out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the below concept

```
if(s1.equals("exit")) {
        break;
}
```

[Please see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490344/how-to-get-out-of-while-loop-in-java-with-scanner-method-hasnext-as-condition)

Comment: if you want to flag a question as a duplicate, you should do that, not post it as an answer. what you posted is a copy-paste ready solution, not a 'concept'. Adding information about why it should be added would be advised

Comment: Works. Thank you